# Not able to print all childs from my firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

[image: Output of all the dates][image: snippet of my firebase database]

I want to print all dates(childs) details from 5th of july to 7th of july from my database but i only get top date(child)[7th july] as my output instead of all of the child nodes**

Here is my reference where i get values from database and put into RecyclerView adapter

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Dateinfo").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mdates.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Dateinfo dateinfo = snapshot.getValue(Dateinfo.class);
                        mdates.add(dateinfo);
                    }
                    Collections.reverse(mdates);
                    dateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my Adapter

```
public class DateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DateAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Dateinfo> mdates;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

public DateAdapter(Context mContext, List<Dateinfo> mdates) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mdates = mdates;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.date_item,parent,false);
    return new DateAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final Dateinfo dateinfo =mdates.get(position);
    holder.date.setText(dateinfo.getDate());
    holder.steps.setText(String.valueOf(dateinfo.getSteps()));
    String timeformat = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%.2f", dateinfo.getDistance());
    holder.distance.setText(timeformat);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Math.min(mdates.size(),10);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView date;
    public TextView steps,distance;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        date=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateview);
        steps=itemView.findViewById(R.id.steps);
        distance=itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    }
}
```

This is my Dateinfo class:

```
public class Dateinfo {
    long steps;
    String ID;
    String date;
    double distance;

    public Dateinfo() {
    }

    public Dateinfo(long steps, String ID, String date, double distance) {
        this.steps = steps;
        this.ID=ID;
        this.date=date;
        this.distance=distance;

    }
    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public long getSteps() {
        return steps;
    }

    public void setSteps(long steps) {
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }



    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. If you set a breakpoint on `Dateinfo dateinfo = snapshot.getValue(Dateinfo.class);` and run in a debugger, does it hit that line multiple times? Does the `dateinfo` then have the info you expect it to have? (since we can't see the `Dateinfo` class, we can't verify that)

Comment: It seems like it is overlapping the previous date or i would say it is printing dates on top of each other and I have added the output of my dates

Comment: And i have added the Dateinfo class above

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: If `Dateinfo dateinfo = snapshot.getValue(Dateinfo.class);` is called for each date, then the correct data is being loaded and it may indeed be a layout issue. I'm not an expert on those, so can't be of much help there. But in that case I'd recommend trying to reproduce the same problem without using Firebase (for example by hard-coding the `Dateinfo` objects in your code. By removing Firebase as a potential cause of problems, it's more likely that someone with the right knowledge will be able to help you.